# regular html not working in JSFiddle

Tags: html, css, wrapper, jsfiddle

How come when I am in a specific wrapper for example http://jsfiddle.net/jspence29/UpHEU/the html tags aren't working. the `<ol>, <ul>, <li>, <p>` and more tags don't work inside this wrapper. you can see that the list isn't working in that jsfiddle

Comment: What do you mean they're not working?  You don't have any such tags in there.

Comment: How are they not working? http://jsfiddle.net/burn123/UpHEU/1/ That works fine

Comment: My apologies, I forgot to save the marked up version, I edited it now!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What's happening is that JSFiddle is applying it's own *reset stylesheet*. You can disable it by unchecking *Normalized CSS* in the left hand column.